# Does the way I create and store layers in subclassed Keras `Model` have any effect?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

AKA Keras `Model` subclassing magic.

While playing with Keras, I noticed, that `ResNetBlock.layers` gets populated as I put new instances of layers into collections I previously put into my custom model.

```py
class ResNetBlock(Model):
    PART_COUNT = 3

    def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
        super().__init__()
        self.convs = []
        self.batchNorms = []

        for part in range(ResNetBlock.PART_COUNT):
            if part == 1:
                conv = Conv2D(filters[part], kernel_size=kernel_size, padding="same")
            else:
                conv = Conv2D(filters[part], kernel_size=(1,1))
            self.convs.append(conv)
            self.batchNorms.append(BatchNormalization())

resnet = ResNetBlock(1, [1, 2, 3])
print(resnet.layers) # actually prints non-empty list
                     # filled with Conv2Ds and BNs from above
```

Adopted from official tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/custom_layers

A bit of digging into TensorFlow source showed, that some kind of tracking is used via `__setattr__` in `Network` class.

Now the code is not trivial, documentation lacking, and it seems unclear if the order of creating new layers/adding them to respective collections matters at all? E.g. if I first fill in `convs` collection, and only then `batchNorms` collection, would it still be the same model?

In most tutorials each layer is actually put into its own attribute.

Bonus question is: why is it done so implicitly? This kind of magic kinda breaks the motto to prefer explicit over implicit. What if for some reason I'd need to use a custom collection type not derived from `list`? How would I ensure these magic operations are done properly?

Answer (score 2):

The order won't matter. What really changes your model is the `call` method. This stores the order of the operations (even if the order of the weights were variable, they would be applied in the same graph with the same functions)

Now, if you suspect that not using a "property", but using another kind of storage for the layers, would not register the layer for some reason, you can double check with:

```
print(len(resnet.trainable_weights))
```

The count should be `6 * PART_COUNT`:

- 2 tensors for the conv layers (kernel and bias)
- 4 tensors for the BatchNormalization layers (mean, variance, scale and offset)

Comment: Yeah, I already know that my custom collection is not supported, as my `.layers` ends up empty. Question is more on what is it that I could explicitly do to get my stuff registered properly.

Comment: But you didn't use any of the layers, they're not supposed to appear in the model if they aren't part of the graph. Again, the important part is the `call` method that you didn't write in the question.

Comment: I omitted the code of `def call(...): ...` for brevity, as it has no effect on contents of `.layers`. Just running the `__init__` is enough to get it populated unless I use a custom collection. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/31a51431d4b27ae9879d3594d710adfc0b2c32fc/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py#L418

Comment: If you don't use "call", the model will not get built at all. It will not have a graph, it will not know its layers. Init is not enough

Comment: If you run the code I posted in TF 1.1x without ever doing `call`, you will see `layers` populated.